# How do I import the default Scripts folder into a blank mvc4 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I created an empty MVC4 application. It doesn't contain the Scripts folder or any of the javascript files.

I need some of those js files.

How do I add them to my project? I can add a new folder, and download/add each JS file individually, but there has to be a better way. I know VS has them somewhere....

Example:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`~/Scripts` doesn't exist. Is there anyway that I can just import the folder with the default JS files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NuGet`.  `NuGet` will correctly place JavaScript dependent frameworks into the `~\Scripts` directory.

Right click on `References->Manage NuGet Packages`.

I used `NuGet` in my Project to pull down `jQuery 1.9.1` as a dependency into my `ASP.NET MVC4 Solution`.

[image: NuGet]

I verified that this brought in the following into my `~\Scripts` directory:

- jquery-1.9.1-intellisense.js
- jquery-1.9.1.js
- jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- jquery-1.9.1.min.map

Here is my Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]

This is a clean way to manage your default scripts (such as `jQuery`, `knockout`, or `modernizr`) via `VS.NET` and `NuGet`.

Comment: Using NuGet is great, I thought of this answer, but refrained to give it for a very simple reason - the guy doesn't know in advance what scripts to bring it (which is implicit in this question). If he does - then its a no-brainer. But the way to know is to look into the existing project.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a new Internet application and just going into the project files and copying them over to the empty project.

There has to be a better way so leaving the question open for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Create non empty project (it will contain all the scripts you need), then just copy them to your empty project into "Scripts" folder and take a look into few places how to include them into the project:

- Global.asax
- App_Start\BundleConfig.cs

That's all you need to do. Thanks & hope this helps!